# Grab or Fetch the deleted words from from_string in FineDiff Library

Tags: php

I am using [FineDiff](https://github.com/gorhill/PHP-FineDiff) library for string comparison. It's an awesome library for string comparison in PHP. But the only problem that I am facing is that I want to fetch and store the only deleted (wrongly typed words which is highlighted with red color in final result) in a string.